# import mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a database in my sql, I have a database which its name is `a` in mysql and the name of database is `a.sql`. I am trying to run the command:

```
/var/lib/mysql -u root -p a < a.sql;
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/var/lib/mysql -u root -p a < a.sql' at line 1
```

Should I exactly write the path of mysql, like:

```
/var/lib/mysql -u root -p a < /home/guest/db/a.sql;
```

I also tries this one but I got the same error.
I googles a lot and tries everything but still I am getting the same error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already in mysql console, use

```
source /home/guest/db/a.sql;
```

if you're in unix shell - use what you're trying to use.

The current error appears because you're running the unix shell command in mysql shell.

Comment: @sanaz bahargam: obviously `/var/lib/mysql` is not a binary on your machine. It's OS dependent. Just run it as `mysql`